# How to find or create a record with Prisma?

Tags: prisma

Is this the best way to find or create a user in Prisma?

```
prisma.user.upsert({
  where: {
    id: user.id,
  },
  update: {
    id: user.id,
  },
  create: {
    id: user.id,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 33):

Yes, you can use `upsert` to create a record. If the `update` property is empty, the record will not be updated.

Example:

```js
const upsertUser = await prisma.user.upsert({
  where: {
    email: 'test@prisma.io',
  },
  update: {},
  create: {
    email: 'test@prisma.io',
    name: 'Test User',
  },
})
```

We plan to document this better: how upsert can behave as a `findOrCreate`. The link to the GitHub issue can be found [here](https://github.com/prisma/docs/issues/640)

For more information regarding upsert, you can read more in the Prisma Client API [Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#upsert) section.

Comment: How to handle if email exist in Prisma? When using Sequelize, we can handle like this following code. https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/sequelize+findorcreate